# How can i calculate median survival adjusted for covariates (age, gender and other covariates)

Tags: r, survival

I am doing a study on a disease. I have done KM-plot, and cox analysis. However I can not figure out how i can calculate the median survival adjusted for age, gender and other covariates. This is interessting because I have four different timeperiods id like to compare. Do anyone know how and if it can be done in R?

The variables i have are:

time_onset_death # Time from symptom onset to death, if not dead, end is set to end of study
Dead # Is the patient dead?
group # 1,2,3 or 4 (by time period)
What i want to today is calculate the median survival for the four groups adjusted for covariates (age and gender).

I not sure what function to use? I am thinking a cox function, but I can only manage to get hazards.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `adjusted_surv_quantile` function (https://robindenz1.github.io/adjustedCurves/reference/adjusted_surv_quantile.html) from the `adjustedCurves` package (https://github.com/RobinDenz1/adjustedCurves).

Since you did not give a reproducible example I cant provide one for you. But the documentation of the function I mentioned above does contain examples.